# Create a New AWS RDS Instance of only one database from a snapshot

Tags: sql-server, restore, amazon-rds, aws

I'm trying to Create a new AWS RDS SQL Server instance of only one database from a snapshot.

I've gone through the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_RestoreFromSnapshot.html), but according to it when I restore from a snapshot it will create all the databases that were in it.

I wanted to just create a new instance with just one specific database from the snapshot.

I was hoping to achieve it using AWS SDK for .NET either using powershell or C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDS Snapshots capture the entire server.

There isn't a way to restore only one database.

Answer (score -1):

Create a new RDS instance from the snapshot.
Then extract the single database from it and populate your specific dB.
Once done, remove the new instance you no longer need.

Comment: but then why would you even restore it?